# replace plank with docky in elementary os

Tags: elementary-os, docky

I am running a fresh install of elementary os freya.
I would like to replace the default plank with docky.
Is it possible and how ??

> PS I have already installed elementary tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite simple. I did it since I prefer the fancier animations (since plank is based on docky, it would be wonderful if it included the same functionality, but that's another thread).

1. Install docky from the Software Center (or from the Docky [PPA](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Installation)).
2. In System Settings, open Tweaks, then click **Cerbere** (under Applications).
3. Click the **plank** entry in the Watched Processes list, then click the minus sign at the bottom of the panel to remove the entry.
4. Now click the plus sign; in the popup that appears, type docky and click the green plus sign to add docky to the list.
5. Still in System Settings, click **All Setings** to return to the main settings window.
6. Click **Applications**.
7. In the Applications window, click **Startup** to bring up your list of startup applications.
8. Click the plus sign and select **Docky** from the list. (Note: If plank is in the startup list, be sure to remove it.)
9. Log out (or restart), log in, and enjoy your new dock.

Note that docky loads with its own default set of docked applications. Would be nice if it picked up the applications from your plank setup, but not a big deal.